# How to set the form as not resizable in C++ Builder?

Tags: forms, c++builder

In C++ Builder how can I set the form's window as not resizable?
Is there some property that needs to be set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the Form's [`BorderStyle`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Forms.TCustomForm.BorderStyle) property to one of the non-resizable styles that is not `bsSizeable` or `bsSizeToolWin`:

- `bsNone`: Not resizable; no visible border line
- `bsSingle`: Not resizable; minimize/maximize menu
- `bsDialog`: Not resizable; no minimize/maximize menu
- `bsToolWindow`: like `bsSingle` but with a smaller caption

Answer (score 2):

This is kind of a primitive way, but it works:

Find `Constrains` in `Object Inspector` -> `Properties`

If you set:

`MaxHeight`equal to `MinHeight`

and

`MaxWidth`equal to `MinWidth`

this will also make your `TForm` non-resizable.